# Which current raid bosses have the potential for being shiny to catch after it’s defeated?

Tags: pokemon-go

Ex: If I take down a Snorunt raid boss, is there a chance it could be shiny when it’s catch time?   Or is a shiny snorunt only possible by catching in the wild? (Same question for  Sableye, Swablu, etc )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

General rule for this is that if the Pokemon has the possibility to be shiny when encountered in the wild, it can also be shiny in the catch-phase of the raid. The current possible shiny raid bosses are:

- Aggron
- Absol
- Mawile
- Sableye
- Magikarp
- Swablu
- Snorunt